# Checking the value of two integers in if statement not working jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two values; adults and children. I am creating a form where the user cannot exceed the combine maximum amount of both values. The value is produced depending on the click of two buttons however the variable: combinedValueNumber dose not change on click. This leads me to believe that even though the numbers change visually the value of the input dose not change. As this data will be submitted it is imperative that the value is recorded. How do I do this?

```
childVal = parseInt($('#pageSearch-children').val());
adultVal = parseInt($('#pageSearch-adults').val());
minValueChild = parseInt($('#pageSearch-children').attr('min'));
maxValueChild = parseInt($('#pageSearch-children').attr('max'));
minValueAdult = parseInt($('#pageSearch-adults').attr('min'));
maxValueAdult = parseInt($('#pageSearch-adults').attr('max'));
maxAbsolute = parseInt(( maxValueChild + maxValueAdult ) / 2);
combinedValueNumber = parseInt(adultVal + childVal);
if (combinedValueNumber < maxAbsolute) {
    $('.add').click(function() {
      if (childVal < maxValueChild) {
        $('#pageSearch-children').val(function(i, oldval) {
          return ++oldval;
        });
        childVal = $('#pageSearch-children').val();
      }
    });
    $('.sub').click(function() {
      if (childVal > minValueChild) {
        $('#pageSearch-children').val(function(i, oldval) {
          return --oldval;
        });
        childVal = $('#pageSearch-children').val();
      }
    });

    adultVal = $('#pageSearch-adults').val();
    minValueAdult = $('#pageSearch-adults').attr('min');
    maxValueAdult = $('#pageSearch-adults').attr('max');
    $('.add2').click(function() {
      if (adultVal < maxValueAdult) {
        $('#pageSearch-adults').val(function(i, oldval) {
          return ++oldval;
        });
        adultVal = $('#pageSearch-adults').val();
      }
    });
    $('.sub2').click(function() {
      if (adultVal > minValueAdult) {
        $('#pageSearch-adults').val(function(i, oldval) {
          return --oldval;
        });
        adultVal = $('#pageSearch-adults').val();
      }
    });
}


<div id="field1" class="centered">
    <h3 class="white black">
        <input class="backgroundNoneInput" type="number" value="1" id="pageSearch-adults" name="adults" min="0" max="{{ $property->property_sleeps or '99' }}" readonly> 
        Adults
    </h3>
    <button type="button" class="sub2 backgourndNoneButt faded">
        <span class="white fa fa-minus fa-2x faPlusMin" aria-hidden="true">                      
        </span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="add2 backgourndNoneButt">
        <span class="white fa fa-plus fa-2x faPlusMin" aria-hidden="true">                        
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
<div id="field2" class="centered">
    <h3 class="white black">
        <input class="backgroundNoneInput" type="number" value="0" id="pageSearch-children" name="children" min="0" max="{{ $property->property_sleeps or '99' }}" readonly> 
        Children
    </h3>
    <button type="button" class="sub backgourndNoneButt faded">
        <span class="white fa fa-minus fa-2x faPlusMin" aria-hidden="true">                      
        </span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="add backgourndNoneButt">
        <span class="white fa fa-plus fa-2x faPlusMin" aria-hidden="true">                        
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should the value of `combinedValueNumber` change? `combinedValueNumber = parseInt(adultVal + childVal);` (`parseInt()` is unecessary) is only executed once.

Comment: @Andreas because the value of adultVal + childVal change onclick.

Comment: They won't change either because of the same reason.

Comment: they change visually, displays a new number on click.. but i need the value and the number to change. Any advice?

Comment: did you forget to update `combinedValueNumber`?

Comment: @david please supply an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you update the value in `input`, makes sure that you update `combinedValueNumber`. This is the example for child.

```
$('.add').click(function() {
  if (childVal < maxValueChild && combinedValueNumber < maxAbsolute) {
    $('#pageSearch-children').val(function(i, oldval) {
      return ++oldval;
    });
    childVal = $('#pageSearch-children').val();
    combinedValueNumber++;
  }
});
$('.sub').click(function() {
  if (childVal > minValueChild && combinedValueNumber < maxAbsolute) {
    $('#pageSearch-children').val(function(i, oldval) {
      return --oldval;
    });
    childVal = $('#pageSearch-children').val();
    combinedValueNumber--;
  }
});
```

The same goes for adult.

Comment: thank you, this dose change the value. Definitely helped me in the right direction. However my plan is that combinedValueNumber can never be more than maxAbsolute.. If it is then the functions inside the if statement dont run. However they still do. Why is this?

Comment: Hey dude, i am now trying to style some buttons so the show they are disabled.. heres my current code.. what would you recommend.?     

$('.add, .sub, .add2, .sub2').click(function() {
        if (childVal == maxAbsolute) {
            $('.add').addClass('faded');
        }
        else {
            $('.add').removeClass('faded');
        }
        if (childVal == 0) {
            $('.sub').addClass('faded');
        }
        else {
            $('.sub').removeClass('faded');
        }
    });

Comment: if you want to disable the button, try this `$('.add').attr('disabled', true);`